# Android Floating Action button screen ignore screen scale

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

i have problem with FloatingActionButton in RelatieLayout. I use DP for margin top and left. When i change device button is not on it's place. You can see on screens. First one is from editor, second from device.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFloor5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_calendar"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:id="@+id/floorActionButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[[image: layout in editor[1]][image: this is how it looks on device]

I also tried `android:gravity="center|bottom"` but nothing happens.

Comment: what you want achieve ?

Comment: i just edited post. Now you can see problem on second img.

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginXXX` from `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: for same place remove both margin. set device on  your editor after that check.

Comment: margin prompt the view for fix place, avoid giving margin for better code and UI.

Comment: Ok, but then how i can move button to left bottom corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried android:gravity="center|bottom" but nothing happens.

Since you are using `RelativeLayout` - `gravity` won't work. Instead use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` along with the margins

```
<RelativeLayout
    ....

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_calendar"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:id="@+id/floorActionButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...Don't use margin to set `FloatingActionButton` position always use `gravity`.

Follow this tutorial from androidhive.

https://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/

I have set `layoutgravity` but use appropriately according to the `parentlayout` `properties` for `gravity`.

If you follow the tutorial above it will be easy for in my case i placed the fab in a `</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>` and included the layout inside it like in the tutorial.

Just follow it it will be easy just don't use `margin` to set its `position` it will `break` in different screens like your above `error` .

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floorActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_calendar"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>
```